# What does the Data Extension Tracking Tab display?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a number of Random Data Extensions in my org which is used for adhoc sends, navigating to the Data Extension within Email Studio there is a Tracking tab which displays send performance of what I assume is the Subscribers within the given data extension.

There is also a Recent Sends: Last 30 days which is displayed alongside it, can someone confirm if this is ALL sends or only sends using this data extension? Looking at one of the Send ID's in more detail, its Data Extensions value does not match up with the Data Extension Tracking Page it was listed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. There's not much insights you can get from DE Tracking since it always shows 'all subscribers' (or status for a publication list). I use it as a shortcut to move to 'Tracking' tab or to a particular job.